# Socrata return all datasets in JSON

Tags: json, url, dataset, socrata, soda

I need a list of all datasets in JSON.

An URL like this: https://data.ct.gov/resource/hma6-9xbg.json returns a single dataset.

Is there an URL that returns me all datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution.
For having a list of all datasets in JSON you need to add data.json at the end of the URL like this: http://data.ct.gov/data.json

Comment: Yep! That's correct! Sorry for the delay in getting to this one, we've all been disconnected over the holidays. It looks like you also filed a trouble ticket, I'll follow up there too.